# Test Automation (Flow)

Tags: unit-testing, user-interface, automated-tests

My Intention is to test the functional flows of the application. So i think best way is testing UI for the steps of the functional flow. (E.g : Add item, after search it and add pricing etc.). My concern is to find best automation tool which should support for desktop application. does anyone have handheld experience of doing this. As a coding guy i don't have experience in Testing.

Additionally: the application is huge application which have connected with oracle database. So it need to clear the database as startup of the testing. So tool should support this matter also.

Programming language :  C#

I found Selenium (but this is only for web application), Renorex and IBM rational Functional Tester.

is my approach(test UI steps for Functional steps) correct? have any one work on above tools or any other best tools whcih support to C# windows application.

I think NUnit is best for text unit test in this project. am i correct? according to my research google i found this as result.

Comment: Spend 80% of your time on unit testing, and the other 20% for UI/Perf/Compat/... testing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @qxg. What do you mean by "UI/Perf/Compat/... testing"?

Comment: @IsuruWijeratna - I think qxg telling about UI- layout , performance and compatibility.

Comment: thank you @HelpingHands. As it have a lot of functional flows, need to automate testing. So is my approach correct?

Comment: Did you try with QTP? as that is best for window application automation.

Comment: Thank You @helping Hand. I will looking  to it. Now the challenge is to find out Open source Tool. I have found SIKULI and QAliber. Have any one worked with it.?

Comment: No.. Actually I work with web applications only.. :) So using selenium webdriver.

Comment: Hai, First i like to thank you all here and down in comments. I have tried "Test Complete" application. it is a paid but it has 30 day trial period. at the moment it is best fit with UI automation testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to keep it short. A good fit for you case

> automation tool which should support for desktop application.

and

> Programming language : C#

will be the VisualStudio's build in [Coded UI test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx). All actions performed on the desktop will be recorded. Pause the recording if you are performing actions that may lead to sensitive data being included in the recording. When coded UI tests are automated, they have to interact with the desktop when you run them, unlike other automated tests.

As far as you try to keep the tests close to the Test pyramid

[image]

the QA effort should be acceptable and your

> approach(test UI steps for Functional steps)

will be correct and feasible. In general try to avoid long and fragile tests, except for some [E2E](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/end_to_end_testing.htm) tests that will exercise the (most business valuable) end-user journeys.

With C# should be relatively easy to [drop oracle database](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/working-with-oracle-databases-using-ado-net/) for your

> need to clear the database as startup of the testing.

Such DB cleaning is often used [Fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/test%20fixture%20-%20xUnit.html) strategy. Take a look at this [Persistent Fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Testing%20With%20Databases.html). Usage of such DB fixtures can be put to work for all conditions that your UI tests expect/rely on (avoid UI setup for tests), example - create available and applicable bonuses.

Another way for your UI layer tests could be some of the .Net based [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) implementations:

- [SikuliSharp](https://github.com/christianrondeau/SikuliSharp)
- [SikuliIntegrator](https://qaagent.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/how-to-use-sikuli-in-my-c-coded-tests/)
- [sikuli4net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sikuli4net/)